# Kendo ListView submit selected items as nested property, MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-listview

I have a form with model and nested property of type `List<string>`. I am populating `listview` on `combobox` change:

```
<script>
    function codeSelect(e)
    {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        var listView = $("#Accounts").data("kendoListView");

        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: /*some url*/
                }
            }
        });
        listView.setDataSource(dataSource);
        listView.refresh();
    }
</script>

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.Code)
    .BindTo(/*somedata*/)
    .DataTextField("CompanyName").DataValueField("code")
    .Events(ev => { ev.Select("codeSelect"); }))

@(Html.Kendo().ListView(Model.Accounts)
    .Name("Accounts")
    .Selectable(sel => sel.Mode(ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .ClientTemplateId("accounts_template")
    .TagName("div")
    .DataSource(dataSource =>  {    
        dataSource.Model(model => model.Id(p => p)); })
)
```

Everything works fine, except when I submit the form I receive list of `Accounts` with 0 rows. How can I bind the listView selected items to it?